# issue with countDownTimer

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I am trying to add countDownTimer, this is working (As long the `curTime` is before `endTime`) I do get the 'Finished' message. My goal is after it's finished I want to restart the timer again. If I comment out the `counter.start();` It does crash: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.CountDownTimer android.os.CountDownTimer.start()' on a null object reference`

Any suggestions?

```
    public void loadCountDownTodaysLikes() {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        String curTime = SharedPrefManager.getCurTime();
        String endTime = "21:01:20";
        Date curTimeD, endTimeD;
        try {
            curTimeD = formatter.parse(curTime);
            endTimeD = formatter.parse(endTime);
           long curLong = curTimeD.getTime();
            long endLong = endTimeD.getTime();
            diff = endLong - curLong;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        counter = new CountDownTimer(diff, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                long millis = millisUntilFinished;
                String hms =
                        (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis) - TimeUnit.DAYS.toHours(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(millis)) + " : ")
                                + (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)) + " : "
                                + (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis))));
                countDownTodays.setText("Resetting in: " + hms);
         
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                countDownTodays.setText("finished!");
                //counter.start();
            }
        }
                .start();
    }
```

Comment: Is counter an instance variable?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, I had to do some edits because I was assuming what your variables were. Is it possible your:

```
String curTime = SharedPrefManager.getCurTime();
```

is the problem? I didn't set this up in my example because I don't know how it looks on your side, I just used :

```
   String curTime = "21:01:15";
```

the timer resets every time. Try logging your curTime and see if you're getting it back as expected. Use  `Log.i("CurTime", curTime);`

Hope this helps some!